# Efficient way to "apply to all" with EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a search page which allows users to search for an item and add details to an item. I am working on allowing users to apply the same details to several items. The user will check all the items he would like to apply the same changes to and click a `Comment` button. This will send a list of items checked `List<int> ids` and the particular item clicked (to use as template in case it already exists) `int id`.

From here the user will edit the comment however he wishes and save. How will the `HttpPost Edit` action look? It is required to add a comment to the database if it doesn't exist for that item already, otherwise, overwrite what exists. Below is what I have come up with (basic outline). The problem I see with this is that it requires poking the database for every item I want the changes applied to. There has to be a better way to do this.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(CommentVM model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        foreach(int i in model.ids)
        {
            Comment comment = _db.Comments.Find(i);
            if(comment == null){
                //Create and add
            {
            else{
                comment.Text = model.Text;
                _db.Entry(comment).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }

        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a sort of homebrew method. Since both cases (add entry and edit entry needed to be handled separately, I handled them as such.

```
List<int> InDB = _db.Comments           
    .Where(r => model.ids.Contains(r.id))
    .Select(r => r.id)
    .ToList();

List<int> diff = model.ids.Except(InDB).ToList();
//Loop through items to ADD
foreach (int i in diff)
{
    Comment comment = new Comment { Text = model.Text, id = i };
    _db.Comments.Add(comment);
}
//Loop through items to edit
foreach (int i in InDB)
{
    Comment comment = new Comment { Text = model.Text, id = i };
    _db.Entry(comment).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I see with this is that it requires poking the database
>   for every item I want the changes applied to.

You needn't worry about this. The database gets called once when you save your changes. The looping affects only the objects in memory. As for your code you seem to be on the right track, but I do have one potential suggestion.  Given your different steps for modifying or creating a comment, I assume that you have written and stored your comments as distinct entities which are linked by id to your items. If this is the case, I would suggest making "Comment" a property of the item, so that way you simply write to the property and simplify the process as a whole.

Comment: Does `Comment comment = _db.Comments.Find(i);` not access the database on each call? Also, the scenario provided is a simplified version of my actual case, thus the need for `Comment` to be it's own entity. I do appreciate the input though!

Comment: Not necessarily. If the object has been loaded already by the data context then it will be pulled directly from the context and not the database (that is the beauty of `find`). If there are a lot of entities that probably won't have already been selected, however, you could do a pre-selection using a `Contains` statement and then loop through that result. The reason why I asked about the property is because if it was a property you could use `Zip` and reduce the whole thing to a line or two ;).

Comment: If only it were that easy! I have come up with a slightly better solution for now. I find elements that exist in `model.ids` that do not currently exist in the database. I loop through that subset and create a new `Comment` and use `_db.Comments.Add()`. I then loop through the rest of the elements in `model.ids` and edit those entities. This should only touch the database twice, once to create a list of `ids` and another to save changes.

Comment: A pre-search with a `Contains` (with your model ids) will get those that exist (first db hit). You can then edit those, create those which do not exist and then do a save changes (second db hit).